# Find $\rho(S,N)$ of a coin

Tags: probability, statistics

> Flipping a fair coin with number $1$ is his first side and $-1$ in the other side of the coin, Let $S$ be the sum of the results, let $N$ be the number of times that we got got the number $1$, find $\rho(S,N)$

I found the answer from old notebook that:

$S=1\cdot N+(-1)(n-N)=2N-n$ therefore $\rho(S,N)=1$

I don't understand the answer or don't know how to evaluate $\rho$

Comment: Because $S$ is just a linear function of $N$. If you know the number of times you flipped the coin ($n$), and you know the number of times you got a 1 ($N$), then you know $S$ with probability one.

Comment: Is the number of times the coin is tosses constant (i.e. not random)? If so you ought to mention that. Is that number $n$? I'd have stated that too.